# Downloading xml file from https url

Tags: .net, vb.net, https, webclient, visual-studio-2003

I am having problem downloading a file from HTTPS website, and i am using vb.
I have this code , its simple but the main problem is that it need to be in Visual Studio 2003.
Here is the code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim client As New WebClient
    ' Download string.
    client.DownloadFile("https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/sites/www.un.org.sc.suborg/files/consolidated.xml", "consolidated.xml")

End Sub
```

But after i start the project i get a message telling me that:

> Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS.

Any way to get around this secure channel?
Thanks

Comment: The only viable solution is to upgrade to .NET 4.6 and Visual Studio 2015 - the Community edition is free. .NET 1.1 is no longer supported and probably didn't have TLS support at all. TLS 1.2 didn't even exist back then. You simply *can't* connect to a modern site that uses TLS 1.2 using .NET 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with this line of code

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
```

Just if someone need :)

Comment: Not really, and your code will probably break very soon. `SecurityProtocolType.Tls` is TLS 1.0 which *is* old and replaced with 1.1 or 1.2 in most sites. Your code hard-codes a dependency on 1.0 and will break the first time you encounter a site that requires 1.2 as many do. You really, really, really must upgrade to a supported .NET version

Answer (score 0):

That works as you have it, **but** the file needs to be a *fully qualified path* to a file and you have to have permissions to write to it.

Try creating a temp file and see if that works:

```
    'create a temp file
    Dim path = IO.Path.GetTempPath()
    Dim fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml"
    Dim fullyQualifiedPath = IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName)

    'download the file
    Using client As New WebClient
        client.DownloadFile("https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/sites/www.un.org.sc.suborg/files/consolidated.xml", fullyQualifiedPath)
    End Using

    'show the file so we can see what we downloaded
    Process.Start(fullyQualifiedPath)
```

Note that you should wrap the WebClient in a Using block as this disposes of the object

Comment: I did all that you told me, but the problem is not with the path. This code that you wrote will work on all versions after 2008, but not on 2003.
I am still getting the same message with the secure channel..thanks

Comment: OK I can't test that

Comment: @СашкоМицевски neither VS 2003 nor .NET 1.1 which it targeted are supported any more. I seriously doubt whether .NET 1.1 had TLS support, much less TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2. TLS 1.2 was added in 4.5.2. TLS autonegotiation was added in 4.6.

Answer (score -2):

@Matt Wilko

That's what I get by using https:

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)

By using http it works